# WordPress website: homepage redirects to "login" page (non-existent now)

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

So I have a wordpress website as my own company site. It has functioned well for as long as it has been up, until now.

(PS, I know the hosting is awfully slow, I am working on sorting this too.)

So lets start from the beginning:

Basically, I wanted to add a log in option, but not site wide; I wanted a customer to have an option to log onto a "customer portal" with credentials that I provide. However, I wanted it to only be available if they navigate to the footer or page and click a button. I did not want it to force any user to log in to use the site.

Stupid me, tried to take a shortcut with the databases and such, and installed something called "Ultimate Member". Essentially, after trying to set this up, my site has now kind of broken. It auto-redirects you to the '/login' page when you go on the home page or when you just search the URL.

So I deleted the plug in, wiped all the data of it, and deleted all the account-related pages. However, now it still directs the user to the '/login' page even though the page no longer exists and I no longer want this function.

As a result, it therefor returns a 404. It has also kind of broken the appearance of my site too, in some pages. I have tried everything and just cannot get rid of this redirection. I've tried other plugins, I've tried searching for it in the editor (files), gone to my database and control panel and looked from there (mySQL and phpMyAdmin). I've tried reinstalling the plug in, deleting each page, reinstalling everything.

By the looks of things, I may have to entirely destroy my site and start over. I ask desperately because I am very pressed for time and cannot really give the time to restart!

Please help!

Website: www.connectdsolutions.co.uk

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disabling maintenance mode? Sometimes after removing intrusive plug ins like that the website will go into a maintenance mode as a default state.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying! I actually turned maintenance mode on myself after my site became unusable. As far as I’m aware it has no effect on the login issue - but thank you for commenting anyway!

Comment: Key @kieron, if you're getting an error or 404 you've got to be receiving some error in your log files. If we could see that error we can probably figure out the issue.

Comment: Yeah that’s true, okay I’ll try to send these over as soon as I’m at my desk! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Once you’ve connected to your site via FTP, find the “.maintenance” file in your root folder and delete it:

Comment: Hi there, thank you for answering! Is this to take it out of maintenance mode? Because I added that myself when my site became unusable!  if this is to solve the logon though, I’ll give it a go. Thanks for your help